# How to remove the login window when a toplevel is opened?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So this is my code below for a login menu. Once the user has logged on I want the login menu to be either hidden or deleted. I've tried `.withdraw()` and `.destroy()`. I'm certain that I'm placing the code in the wrong places, any assistance would be much appreciated!

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3
import hashlib
import os
import weakref


def main():
  root = Tk()
  width = 600 #sets the width of the window
  height = 600 #sets the height of the window
  widthScreen = root.winfo_screenwidth() #gets the width of the screen
  heightScreen = root.winfo_screenheight() #gets the height of the screen
  x = (widthScreen/2) - (width/2) #finds the center value of x
  y = (heightScreen/2) - (height/2) #finds the center value of y
  root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, x, y))#places screen in center
  root.resizable(width=False, height=False)#Ensures that the window size cannot be changed 
  filename = PhotoImage(file = 'Login.gif') #gets the image from directory
  background_label = Label(image=filename) #makes the image
  background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)#palces the image
  logins = login(root)
  root.mainloop()

class login(Tk):
  def __init__(self, master):
    self.__username = StringVar()
    self.__password = StringVar()
    self.__error = StringVar()
    self.master = master
    self.master.title('Login')
    userNameLabel = Label(self.master, text='UserID: ', bg=None, width=10).place(relx=0.300,rely=0.575)
    userNameEntry = Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.__username, width=25).place(relx=0.460,rely=0.575)
    userPasswordLabel = Label(self.master, text='Password: ', bg=None, width=10).place(relx=0.300,rely=0.625)
    userPasswordEntry = Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.__password, show='*', width=25).place(relx=0.460,rely=0.625)
    errorLabel = Label(self.master, textvariable=self.__error, bg=None, fg='red', width=35).place(relx=0.508,rely=0.545, anchor=CENTER)
    loginButton = Button(self.master, text='Login', command=self.login_user, bg='white', width=15).place(relx=0.300,rely=0.675)
    clearButton = Button(self.master, text='Clear', command=self.clear_entry, bg='white', width=15).place(relx=0.525,rely=0.675)
    self.master.bind('<Return>', lambda event: self.login_user()) #triggers the login subroutine if the enter key is pressed

  def login_user(self):
    username = self.__username.get()
    password = self.__password.get()
    hashPassword = (password.encode('utf-8'))
    newPass = hashlib.sha256()
    newPass.update(hashPassword)
    if username == '':
      self.__error.set('Error! No user ID entered')
    elif password == '':
      self.__error.set('Error! No password entered')
    else:
      with sqlite3.connect ('pkdata.db') as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select userID, password from users where userID=?",(username,))
        info = cursor.fetchone()
        if info is None:
          self.__error.set('Error! Login details not found!')
        else:
          dbUsername = info[0]
          dbPassword = info[1]
          if username == dbUsername or newPass.hexdigest() == dbPassword:
            self.open_main_menu()
            self.master.withdraw()
          else:
            self.__error.set('Error! please try again')
            self.clear_entry()

  def destroy(self):
    self.master.destroy()

  def clear_entry(self):
    self.__username.set('')
    self.__password.set('')

  def open_main_menu(self):
    root_main = Toplevel(self.master)
    root_main.state('zoomed')
    Main = main_menu(root_main)
    root_main.mainloop()


class main_menu():
  def __init__(self, master):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: 1: you have two mainloop when you're only supposed to have at most one. 2: login shouldn't be a subclass of Tk since it will make login a "root"

Comment: Naseem, I see from your profile that you've gotten answers for several questions, but you haven't accepted or voted for any of them. I recommend reading [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I can upvote an answer but i have less that 15 rep therefore does not appear publicly. Will upvote those that did help. Thanks Nas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem in your code is that you're calling `mainloop` more than once. As a general rule, you should always call `mainloop` exactly once in a tkinter GUI.

The most common way to do a login window is to make your login window an instance of `Toplevel`, and put your main GUI program in the root window. At startup you can hide the main window and show the login window. If the login succeeds, hide the login window and show the root window.

It looks something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Login(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)

        self.root = root

        username_label = tk.Label(self, text="Username:")
        password_label = tk.Label(self, text="Password:")
        username_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        password_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        submit = tk.Button(self, text="Login", command=self.login)

        username_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e")
        username_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ew")
        password_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="e")
        password_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="ew")
        submit.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="e")

    def login(self):
        # if username and password are valid:
        self.withdraw()
        self.root.deiconify()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()

    label = tk.Label(root, text="this is the main application")
    label.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=100, pady=100)

    login_window =  Login(root)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Just looking into adapting the answer code above to fit in with my own, would you please explain why root is a global variable? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @NaseemTomkinson: it doesn't need to be. That was a mistake. It was left in from an earlier version. I'll fix it.

Comment: How would i open a class, say a main menu screen thats in the zoomed state. I can get it to work without the zoomed state, but with it im having some issues

Comment: @NaseemTomkinson: stackoverflow isn't designed for extended discussions. If you have additional questions, click the "Ask Question" button.