# Problem logic tkinter loguin and main screen

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing because of something that I cannot solve, I wanted to add a login to my program and I am doing it wrong, I want the login not to be the main screen but a toplevel but I do not realize how to use the logic, what is my mistake or mistakes.

```
class Product:

    def __init__(self, window):
      
        self.main_window = window
        self.main_window.title('MAIN SCREEN')

        self.loguin_window = customtkinter.CTkToplevel()
        self.loguin_window.title('LOGUIN SCREEN')
  
        frame_usuario = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self.loguin_window, corner_radius=0)

        button_ingresar = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame_usuario, text='Ingresar',command=self.pantalla_principal)
       

    def pantalla_principal(self):
        
        if self.entry_user.get() == "user" and self.entry_contraseña.get() == "password": 

            self.main_window.deiconify() 
            self.loguin_window.destroy() 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = customtkinter.CTk()
    application = Product(window)
    window.withdraw()
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you look into the source code of `customtkinter` module, the override `.mainloop()` will *deiconify* the window before running `tkinter.mainloop()` if the attribute `window_exists` is False (which is the initial value).  Call `window.update()` (to change the attribute `window_exists` to True) before `window.withdraw()`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to launch the log in prompt from the main screen or have an entirely separate login window? Either way you should check out customtkinter's [documentation](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki). Their wiki has instructions on how to properly set up the root window and toplevel windows as well.

Here is an example of launching a login window from the main window.

```py
import customtkinter


class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Main Screen")
        self.geometry("500x400")
        
        self.button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Login", command=self.login)
        self.button.pack(side="top", padx=40, pady=40)

    def login(self):
        window = customtkinter.CTkToplevel(self)
        window.title("Login Screen")
        window.geometry("400x200")

        # create label on CTkToplevel window
        label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(window, text="Login")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=40, pady=40)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Produces this outcome:

[image: enter description here]

Comment: hello thanks for answering, what I want is that: main_window is my main window and loguin_window is the window that starts the program and that when I start session it closes

Comment: I was looking and what I can not do is adapt the solution of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42912860/how-to-remove-the-login-window-when-a-toplevel-is-opened -> to my code